# What music was Kousei playing in the first episode?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

Right after the OP on the first episode, 11 year-old Kousei is shown playing the piano.

[image: Kousei playing the piano]

What music is he playing? Is this an existing music, or was it something made for the series?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to [this MAL post](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1285841&show=0#post9) I just found out it's [Ludwig van Beethoven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_van_Beethoven)'s [*Piano Sonata No. 14 in C-sharp minor "Quasi una fantasia"*, popularly known as the *Moonlight Sonata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No._14_%28Beethoven%29)'s third and last movement, [*Presto Agitato*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No._14_%28Beethoven%29#Presto_agitato).

[Here's a video](http://youtu.be/oqSulR9Fymg) of the music, played by [Wilhelm Kempff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Kempff).
And [here](http://youtu.be/-B2Cqcb8FzU) another video by one Brandon Ethridge, filmed from the top. This ones makes it look - at least for me - like the animation was done accurately (or at least the progression of the right hand along the keyboard in the animation intends to suggest a minimum of accuracy).

Answer (score 8):

[Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata, 3rd movement.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqSulR9Fymg)

Comment: @JNat Beat me to it :P

Answer (score -1):

Moonlight Sonata - Third Movement.

Comment: This doesn't add anything more to the post that the previous answers haven't already mentioned. Fleshing your answer out with extra description or links will help, most single line answers are deleted